# Handling Unicode Embedded Fonts with Apache Tika PDF Parser

Tags: java, scala, pdf, unicode, apache-tika

I'm trying to parse a complex PDF file using Scala with Apache Tika's PDF parser.

However, the outputs are not the same as the text in the file. I believe, it's because the PDF document has text in languages other than English, thus, the input is Unicode (with embedded fonts).

Is there any way I can handle Unicode in Tika or any other library for Scala/Java (or even something else, if it makes life any easier) to parse such PDF documents?

I was thinking about extracting the embedded font file from PDF; but then again, I need to know how I can specify it to Tika to use a particular font file.

My current code looks like this:

```
val pdf : PDFParser = new PDFParser();

val stream : InputStream = new FileInputStream(file)
val handler : ContentHandler = pdfHandler
val metadata : Metadata = new Metadata()
metadata.add("encoding", "unicode")
val context : ParseContext = new ParseContext()

pdf.parse(stream,
     handler,
     metadata,
     context)

stream.close()
```

Handler object here has only one method:

```
def characters(ch : Array[Char], start: Int, length: Int) {
    println(new String(ch))
}
```

Others are empty to fulfil the abstract class requirements.

Comment: Did you make sure you're using the latest version of Apache Tika? PDF handling generally improves between each version, as Apache PDFBox adds additional support

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes, I'm using the latest version.

Comment: Can you try the [Apache PDFBox PDF to Text command line tool](http://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#extractText) on the file? That'll help work out if it's a Tika issue, or a PDFBox one

Comment: @Gagravarr returns `Sep 01, 2015 5:03:39 PM org.apache.pdfbox.filter.FlateFilter decode
SEVERE: FlateFilter: stop reading corrupt stream due to a DataFormatException`

Comment: I'd suggest you open a bug with PDFBox then, and upload a problematic file so they can investigate!

Comment: @Gagravarr I could. The problem, however, is that the program using Tika is still returning the text without embedded fonts.

Comment: First step is to get PDFBox to be able to get the text. Next challenge is to get Tika able to get that from PDFBox. Until PDFBox can get it, Tika won't be able to ask PDFBox for it!

Comment: @Gagravarr I've fixed the PDFBox issue now. It was a corrupted file. But I still can't get it to produce proper results.